# how to use total-max-memory property

Tags: apache, gemfire, geode

While creating a region in geode you can  specify --total-max-memory which should limit the amount of memory used the the region entries.
ref: https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863

I created a region of type PARTITION_OVERFLOW with total-max-memory set, I can see that this attribute is there in the the partition attributes for the region on server, but when the amount of data crossed the total-max-memory limit it did not start overflowing old entries to disk, after some time(memory usage is almost 10x greater than total-max-memory) the heap lru(which is based on total jvm head) kicks in and starts evicting entries.

Is there any additional setting which has to be done to trigger eviction when total-max-memory limit is reached for a region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total-max-memory is option is not used in geode. Following is the reference JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-2719.